# Building a Twitter like feed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have two `models`, `tweet model` and `retweet model`. They are connected via `polymorphic` association, because comments and retweets itself can be retweeted too.

#### Tweet model

```rb
has_many :retweets, as: :retweetable, dependent: :destroy
```

#### Tweet migration

```rb
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :tweets do |t|
      t.text        :body,      null: false
      t.string      :image
      t.references  :user,      null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### Retweet model

```rb
belongs_to :retweetable, polymorphic: true
has_many :retweets, as: :retweetable, dependent: :destroy
```

#### Retweet migration

```rb
class CreateRetweets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :retweets do |t|
      t.text        :body
      t.string      :uuid
      t.references  :retweetable,       polymorphic: true, null: false
      t.references  :user,              null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :retweets, :uuid
  end
end
```

I want to show all the `retweets` and `tweets` on the home page, like somehow merge the `tweet model` and `retweet model`. Currently, I just have tweets showing up like:

```rb
def index
  @tweets = Tweet.from_people_you_know(current_user)
end
```

I do not want a solution which does something like:

```rb
def index
  @tweets = Tweet.from_people_you_know(current_user)
  @retweets = Retweet.all
end
```

and loop around each of `@tweets` and `@retweets` separately, as it would not show a mix of both the models.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you go with a single model: Tweet. It would also have children (or retweets if you want to call it that way). A retweet is still a tweet.

```
class Tweet
  has_many :retweets, as: :parent, class_name: 'Tweet'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Tweet'
  scope :root_tweets, lamnda {
    where(parent_id: nil)
  }
end
```

This way, you can have only the main tweets:

```
@tweets = Tweet.root_tweets
```

Or all of them, with retweets in between:

```
@tweets = Tweet.all
```

And implement your own scopes, i.e. `from_people_i_know` etc.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: But will polymorphic association work? In my app, comments and retweets itself can be retweeted. By looking at your solution, only the Tweet can be retweeted. Am I right?

Comment: A `Comment` is basically a tweet to another tweet, I wouldn't distinguish between Tweet, Retweet and Comment as they're essentially all tweets.